# PHP call function from function

Tags: php, function, for-loop

Can anyone explain to me what is actually going on in the function?

```
function f($b=0)
{
    echo $b.',';
    /*otuput is 0,1,2,3,4,5,3,4,2,3,4,5,3,*/

    if ($b<3)
    {
        /*echo $b.',';
        when echo is here, otuput is 0,1,2,2,*/

        for ($a=0;$a<3;$a++)
        {
            /*echo $b.',';
            when echo is here, otuput is 0,1,2,3,4,2,3,1,2,3,4,2,*/

            f(++$b);
        }
    }
}

f();
```

Why is output not `0,1,2,0,1,2,0,1,2,`?
And how to do with the calling same function from function?

Comment: Recursion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53840251/php-call-function-from-function

Comment: @AbraCadaver :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all it calls `f(0)` so it displays `0`.

Then it calls `f(1)`, `f(2)` & `f(3)` respectively.

`f(1)`: It displays `1` and runs `f(2)`, `f(3)` & `f(4)`.

`f(2)`: It displays `2` and runs `f(3)`, `f(4)` & `f(5)`.

`f(3)`: It displays `3` only

`f(4)`: It displays `4` only

`f(5)`: It displays `5` only

...

So:

```
f(0):
    {
    0,
    f(1): 
        {
        1, 
        f(2): 
            {
            2, 
            f(3): 
                {
                3
                }, 
            f(4): 
                {
                4
                }, 
            f(5): 
                {
                5
                } 
            },
        f(3):
            {
            3
            },
        f(4):
            {
            4
            }
        },
    f(2):
        {
        2, 
        f(3): 
            {
            3
            }, 
        f(4): 
            {
            4
            }, 
        f(5): 
            {
            5
            } 
        },
    f(3):
        {
        3
        }
    }
```

So the output is: `0,1,2,3,4,5,3,4,2,3,4,5,3,`

Answer (score 0):

This is an effect of recursion. The variable `b` is always within local scope of the function. When you first start the function, `b` value is 0, therefore reaches the for. The `++b` syntax means that b is increased before being evaluated, so when reaching `f(++b)` with `b == 0`, it becomes a `f(1)`. The function then starts the cycle with `b == 1`, and reaches the for. At this point, contrary to what you were expecting, you have the first for still waiting for recursion to finish, when you start the new recursion cycle. This also happens for the next recursion, with `b==2`. So, using some indentation to clarify the cycles:

```
// Prints 0
for ($a = 0; $a < 3; $a++)
   f(++$b)  // $b == 0, $a == 0
      // Prints 1
      for ($a = 0; $a < 3; $a++)
         f(++$b)  // $b == 1, $a == 0
            // Prints 2
            for ($a = 0; $a < 3; $a++)
               f(++$b)  // $b == 2, $a == 0
                 // Prints 3, no further cycles
               f(++$b)  // $b == 3, $a == 1
                 // Prints 4, no further cycles
               f(++$b)  // $b == 4, $a == 2
                 // Prints 5, no further cycles
            // The function returns having completed the cycle
         f(++$b)  // $b == 2, $a == 1
            // Prints 3, no further cycles
         f(++$b)  // $b == 3, $a == 2
            // Prints 4, no further cycles
      // The function returns having completed the cycle
   f(++$b)  // $b == 1, $a == 1
      // Etc. etc.
```

Comment: thank you! hmm. then i have problem because i need do something complex and i need one function which make me correct output format. if you have time, please look at http://www.showcase.sk/php/ would you help me? :)

Comment: I've tried looking into it, but I'm fairly sure there are some mistakes in the example. (there's no Query2 in the NEED set?). The datasets are doing my head in, I don't really understand what's the problem or the correlation. As far as I can tell you need to to merge multiple data structure into a tree, but I fail to see how the above example would solve your issue. Recursion _could_ work, but for each new branch you probably need to [https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php](pass by reference), and the subtree object to be merged.

Comment: ouch, you are right. im update sample. [query2] are for variants in NEED set. my problem is create right output with two different inputs and combine "xml matrix" set with "source dataset" in one function. so order must repeat 6x and in this repeat must repeat product always different (1. loop 3x, 2., 3., 4., loop 1x and 5 loop 2x) and in this repeat must repeat varinats. data are completely dinamic and can be totally different. and that's not for my head :(

Comment: I'm having real problems visualizing your issue, but why not linearize instead of using recursion? Example:
`foreach ($array0 as $order) {  if (/* check if we need to nest*/) { foreach($array1 as $sub-order) { $order[$sub-order] = /*some stuff*/ } }`

Comment: i created image for better understanding. this is the environment http://www.showcase.sk/php/impexp.jpg

Comment: Again, based on your diagram, it looks like you have a limited number of nesting, so you don't really need recursion. You can linearize the integration. Although, I must ask, shouldn't you use a better SQL query to get the proper structure in the first place?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185453/discussion-between-varstahl-and-netoper).